# Do TypeScript interfaces need to be defined in d.ts files?

Tags: typescript

I am writing a TypeScript class:

```
export class Test
{
    property : string;
}
```

I want to extend the Knockout interface, `KnockoutObservable` like for `String`, `Bool` that are already in Knockout.d.ts;

```
export declare interface KnockoutObservableTest extends KnockoutObservableBase
{
    ...
}
```

If I have the interface in my Test.ts file together with the class I cant get it working.
if I put it in a separate App.d.ts file and reference it, it seems to work.

My test is

```
var value : KnockoutObservableTest;
```

Wondering why it have to be in a d.ts file, or maybe there is something I do not know ?

Comment: Have found the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading it from the same file as the `Test.ts` with...

```
import TestModel = module('Test');
```

... the interface is declared in `TestModel.KnockoutObservableTest` in contrast to just being in the root scope when references a `.d.ts` file.